# Do mobs spawn in the same location for every seed in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm interested in knowing whether peaceful mobs spawn in the same location every time in Minecraft for a given map seed. When I was playing on the "Glacier" seed on a singleplayer world, I found a pack of wolves that spawned inside a cave where I could tame them easily. Will they spawn like this every time on this particular seed, or is the spawning of peaceful mobs simply random and unpredictable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## No

The random values for mob spawn times and locations are not taken from the world seed.

Source: My own experimentation. This is super-easy to verify with a super-flat world.

Comment: http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Spawning This quote from the Minecraft Wiki directly contradicts your answer: "Randomness for animal spawning is derived from the world seed, which means that worlds with the same seed will generate chunks with the same animals in the same places." However, I'm not sure whether this is still accurate.

Comment: This should be easy enough to verify by looking at the code from MCP...

Answer (score 1):

They are completely random, however peaceful mobs DO have a higher chance to spawn in specific biomes.

- Pigs: Mostly in Plains and Swamps
- Sheep: Mostly in Plains and Mountains
- Cows: Several biomes, but commonly in forests
- Wolves: Mostly in Forests and Taigas (snowy forest)
- Chickens: Several biomes, but mostly in plains